# Array of text only Matching the last query

Tags: jquery, asp.net, arrays

I have a `repeater control` which I'm trying to add a different class to the matching class name of my query.
My HTML is as Follows:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt_course_list">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="coursedates">
         <div class="coursekey">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="coursetitle"><%# Eval("Title")%></div>
         <div class="coursetype"><%#: Eval("title1") %></div>
         <div class="courselink">
          <a href="<%#: Eval("CoursePageUrl")%>" title="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View</a>
        </div>
       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to see what is in `coursetype` and then set a class on the `coursekey`. I am getting the results and pushing them into an `array` (the array has the correct fields). When I run the code I can only seem the match the last `coursetype` as each `coursekey` will have a different colour but they are always the last colour. How should I get it to match the correct `coursetype` and add the correct class to each `coursekey`.

```
 var names = new Array();
    $('.coursetype').each(function() {
        names.push($(this).text());
        console.log(names);

    });
    if ($.inArray('value1', names) !== -1) {
        $('.coursetype').closest('.coursedates').find('.coursekey').addClass('class1');
    }
    if ($.inArray('value2', names) !== -1) {
        $('.coursetype').closest('.coursedates').find('.coursekey').addClass('class2');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are adding the values in array and complicating things. I will rather do it like this:-

```
$('.coursedates').each(function() {
       var parentDiv = $(this);
       var coursetype = $('.coursetype',parentDiv).text();
        if(coursetype == "value1")
        {
            $('.coursekey',parentDiv).addClass('class1');
        }
        else if (coursetype == "value2")
        {
             $('.coursekey',parentDiv).addClass('class2');
        }
        //and so on..
});
```

Basically, we are looping through the main div `coursedates`, storing it's context in a variable and proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = new Array();
$('.coursetype').each(function() {
    names.push($(this).text());
    console.log(names);

});

if ($.inArray('value1', names) !== -1) {
    $('.coursetype').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.coursekey').addClass('class1');
    });
}

if ($.inArray('value2', names) !== -1) {
    $('.coursetype').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.coursekey').addClass('class2');
    });
}
```